# What is the effect of setting shrinkToFit to an integer?

Tags: jqgrid

In the [jqGrid option docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) it says that you can set shrinkToFit to an integer but doesn't say what effect it has. I was wondering if anyone knew what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. If you look at the source code to [grid.jqueryui.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.jqueryui.js), you can see that the option is passed to internal calls to `setGridWidth` when the grid is resized:

```
$($t).jqGrid('setGridWidth',ui.size.width,opts.shrinkToFit);
```

Then, if you look at [grid.base.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js) you can see how the option is used inside of `setGridWidth`:

```
setGridWidth : function(nwidth, shrink) {
       return this.each(function(){
          ...
          if(typeof shrink != 'boolean') {
              shrink=$t.p.shrinkToFit;
          }
          ...
          if(shrink ===false && $t.p.forceFit === true) {$t.p.forceFit=false;}
          if(shrink===true) {
```

Since each of the `shrink` comparisons is done using type checking (with `===`), these will both be `false` if `shrinkToFit` is an integer. This is the same effect that you would get if `shrinkToFit` and `forceFit` were both set to `false`. There is also similar logic in `setColWidth`. But in both cases the actual integer value of `shrinkToFit` is never used.

The [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) states that

> If the value of shrinkToFit is an integer, the width is calculated according to it.

But I just do not see that based on this code analysis. Maybe this is a feature that is intended for a future release? Or maybe I am missing something? In any case, I would suggest that for now you just pass a boolean value to `shrinkToFit`.